# Sending to my dropbox

Tags: windows, dropbox

I run a seminar and want my speakers to send me their power point so I can place it on 2 laptops for the meeting. How do I allow them to send me the power points that only I will see ?

Comment: Im not sure you can do this with dropbox. One possible solution would be to ask the speakers to upload thier stuff in a zip file protected with an password and mail you the PW.

Answer (score 1):

Get them to send a link to you, not to your dropbox file. Then you will be able to download them and do what you want.

An alternate way would be to assign everyone a separate file folder and don't give them access to the other's folders.